# Ember Data: How do I know if a relationship was changed?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm writing a custom data adapter (doesn't talk to webserver) and I need to know whether `hasMany` relationship was changed or not to persist relationship data.

```
App.Note = DS.Model.extend({
  content: attr('string'),
  createdAt: attr('date'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag', { async: true })
});

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  notes: DS.hasMany('note')
});
```

I need to implement adapter's `updateRecord`:

```
updateRecord: function(store, type, record) {
  // record.changedAttributes() returns changed attributes but not relationships
}
```

In my case list of tags attached to note may change (via `note.get('tags').addObject(..) / removeObject(..)`) so I need to get a diff. What's the best way to do that? I can remove all tags in a database and insert new tags but that's not efficient at all

Comment: Do you want to save the tags, even when the user don't call `model.save()`?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior No, I want to save when `model.save()` gets called.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem?

Comment: @MirkoAkkov No, I think I worked around it so it doesn't require a diff